# Download File from Flask App via Link or Browser

Tags: python, flask

Having a flask app running on remote server, and have files generated that I'd like users to download a file via a browser link (perhaps using ftp prefix?)

Here is a link of a file I put into a browser:

```
 ftp://linuxserver:8991/flask_project/cleaned_files/generated_file.xlsx
 # or
 http://linuxserver:8991/flask_project/cleaned_files/generated_file.xlsx
 # not found
```

The directory called 'flask_project' is where app.py is located.  Any tips on how to access files to be transferred easily through link?

Comment: Flask is an HTTP server, not FTP..?

Comment: http can transfer files just fine.  Avoid FTP whenever possible as its a needlessly complex, insecure, and outdated protocol.

Comment: See this? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory

Comment: @cricket_007 even if I switch to http:// prefix, file still now found

Comment: What route do you have defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server needs to define a route for downloading files

```
@app.route('/cleaned_files/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory("cleaned_files",
                           filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Then that route would be accessed like so

`http://linuxserver:8991/cleaned_files/generated_file.xlsx`